# Magento 2 how to pass if exist search criteria in rest api call

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, search-criteria

**I need to filter getList records in my rest api call.
I have following:**

> searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=city_ref&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=notnull

But it returns all records to me, even if **city_ref** isn't exist in the record.
**I need url parameter like above, because i pass it in ajax.
How to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

I fount the solution. If you want to filter your request, your parameters should be like following:

> searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=field_name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=neq

So, value must be empty and filter must be 'neq'.